# Is there a way to run application with maven cargo:run and attach debugger automatically in idea?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, run-configuration, maven-cargo

I have a run configuration in Idea which runs cargo:run maven goal.
In order to debug it, I need to wait until weblogic starts listening at debugger port:
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9005`. Then I can attach debugger with remote configuration.

However I noticed that when this 'Listening for transport dt_socket' log appears, there is a button in the log to attach debugger:
[image: 'Attach debugger' screenshot]

It seems that Idea 'knows' when debugger can be attached.

So question is: Is there a way (out-of-the-box or plugin) to attach debugger automatically, as soon as weblogic starts listening for it?

End goal is that I can just click once and my application starts in debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried to create Run configuration for debugging and add maven goal in "Before Launch" section?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because maven goal keeps running so debug will never start

Comment: You may try this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13263-attachme/versions